# getting names of features from a pickled model

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I pickled a scikit-learn model after fitting, so if rerun I can use it for prediction without fitting again.

In the following code:

```
# Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

rf_feature_imp = RandomForestClassifier(100)
feat_selection = SelectFromModel(rf_feature_imp, threshold=0.5)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

model = Pipeline([
          ('fs', feat_selection), 
          ('clf', clf), 
        ])

 params = {
    'fs__threshold': [0.5, 0.3, 0.7],
    'fs__estimator__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
 }

 gs = GridSearchCV(model, params, ...)
 gs.fit(X,y)

model = gs.best_estimator_

with open(path_pickle_model, 'wb') as f:
   cPickle.dump(model, f)
```

The model has been subject to a grid search for reducing the number of features. When the model is reread, applying it to data causes a problem since the number of features in the model and data differ.

So, how can I get the names of features from a pickled model that I read from disk?

Comment: what type of model is it? If you performed a feature selection step, you'll need to save that part of the pipeline.

Comment: `dir(.model)` would be a good first step.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaust, edited code to reflect what I am using

Comment: You can use pandas and https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas.